# Schedule PHP script on Synology Server

Tags: php, synology

I have a php script that connects to a database to run a query. This works fine when running the script by browsing to it. The problem I have is when I use the Task Scheduler within the Synology server's control panel. For some reason I am getting the following error:

**PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /volume1/web/bimotech/check_ip.php on line 13**

As mentioned, this works fine when running from the browser but not when scheduled.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though the PHP you're running was built without mysqli, or perhaps mysqli is not loaded.  Can you run a `phpinfo();` and make sure you have mysqli?

Bear in mind that the PHP you use in a CRON job can be different from the PHP that gets run by Apache when your web page executes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the full path of your php, synology maybe using different version of php.

For example your php executable is installed on /usr/bin/php

you have to do something like

```
/usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php
```